# Периодический опрос Телеграм Бота на предмет работоспособности

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть два телеграм бота на Python(pyTelegramBotAPI).
Бывает проблема, что какой-то бот перестаёт отвечать на запросы, пока с этой проблемой я не разобрался, причем фоновые процессы ботов работают и присылают уведомления...

Хочу сделать, чтобы эти два бота периодически опрашивали друг друга. 
Если какой-то бот не отвечает, тогда прислать пользователю т.е. мне уведомление.

Может кто делал, что-то подобное? Как правильно реализовать алгоритм? Пытался сделал наброски, но не успешно...

Comment: боты не могут обмениваться сообщениями между собой, этот принцип лежит в основе апи

Answer (score 1):

Костыль:
Создаем фейк чат и пусть 2 бота по очереди правят к примеру "setChatDescription". Кто свою очередь пропустил тот и "виноват".
Это всего лишь догадка.